# How can I check the current memory management mode for an oracle database instance?

Tags: oracle, memory, windows, oracle-19c

I have a vendor requesting that Automatic Shared Memory Management (ASMM) is configured to a certain threshold for an existing oracle database (version 19c) hosted on a windows box. As usual Oracle documentation seems to be scattered, I am wondering if there is a simple SQL query I can run to see if values were set manually. Based on Oracle's [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/managing-memory.html#GUID-0E0EBCD5-6134-492B-9232-3F76D92B1900) it looks like if "Automatic Memory Managment" was enabled I should see a value for `MEMORY_TARGET` set to something other than 0. In my case when I run `show parameter target;` I am seeing that `MEMORY_TARGET` has a value of 0, so this leads me to believe that "Automatic Memory Managment" is NOT enabled in this case. I'm looking for an easy way to check the current memory management mode configured for an existing Oracle database, either by SQL query or looking at a config file.

[image]

Comment: ASMM refers to `sga_target` (and `pga_aggregate_target`), not `memory_target`. If `sga_target` > 0, you are using ASMM. I never use the DBCA but from the looks of it it's pretty obvious that you have ASMM enabled but not AMM (last radio option).

Comment: @PaulW - The screen shot I provided was just an example I found on the web and not for this specific case. So, if `sga_target` > 0 then I am using ASMM without anything else to check? Can you equate the 3 values for ASMM in the screen shot to those in the management views?

Comment: Again, I don't use GUIs to create databases, but because the slider value is larger my guess is the slider must be `sga_max_size` and the "SGA size" must be `sga_target` (if so, the label is a bit confusing). Your actual shared memory segment allocation on the OS will be `sga_max_size` , while the target is just a mathematical goal for internal memory structures to try to achieve while they are moving memory around between themselves. It is often the same as `sga_max_size` but also commonly a bit less.

Comment: @PaulW - Thanks for the info, if I can share the vitals with you. Maximum SGA Size = 7871MB `sga_target` = 8254MB and I am working with 32GB total RAM. According to the vendors documentation (and based on the size of the db) the memory allocation slider should be set to 2/3 of available memory. What do I need to consider for SGA/PGA? Does ASMM determine that initially?

Comment: Well based on that info, it sounds like I must have got them switched. slider must be target, and the input field must be the max. The target can never be greater than max. With 32GB and knowing nothing else, I'd start out with something modest like 5G SGA (5 max, 4 target) and between 5 and 10GB pga target (which is used only on demand, not constant). You can change those as needed later based on the actual needs of the database. Every db workload is different.

Comment: @PaulW - No you were right, I typo'd `sga_target` it is equal to `sga_max_size`

Comment: @PaulW - Does this config follow what is outlined in the screen shot for ASMM?

ALTER SYSTEM SET sga_max_size=21845M scope=spfile;
ALTER SYSTEM SET SGA_TARGET=16384M SCOPE=BOTH;
ALTER SYSTEM SET SHARED_POOL_SIZE = 0 SCOPE=BOTH;
ALTER SYSTEM SET LARGE_POOL_SIZE = 0 SCOPE=BOTH;
ALTER SYSTEM SET JAVA_POOL_SIZE = 0 SCOPE=BOTH;
ALTER SYSTEM SET DB_CACHE_SIZE = 0 SCOPE=BOTH;
ALTER SYSTEM SET STREAMS_POOL_SIZE = 0 SCOPE=BOTH;

Comment: Yes. Although those pool sizes default to 0 so you'd only need to set them to 0 if they had been previous set to something else. Also use scope=spfile for everything. You're going to need to bounce no matter what, and some of those won't take on a running instance even if they are permitted to attempt the change in memory